# Need to get Array Element

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I have a need to get element in the array.

```
States =[MiN_LENGTH = 2, MIN_PWD_LENGTH = 8]

var result =  this.States.map(t=> t.MIN_PWD_LENGTH);
```

Comment: Actually, it's not an array!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale In this syntax, it is an array of integer

Comment: This is an array of object: States = [{"id" : 1},{"id" : 2},{"id" : 3}];

Comment: @CharlieH yup! Checked that!

Comment: @amit Its actually Integer array so If you console the value of `States` will print the `[2,8]` which don't have any key like `MIN_PWD_LENGTH` that why it is not working!

Comment: actually i have need to get column name with value. and state is declared that   States: any[];

Comment: @amit So you can create a new array by this integer array

Comment: @amit will this variable `States` contain more element than 2

Answer (score 1):

Hope this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kyfymh) will help you.

.ts

```
 States = [{ MiN_LENGTH: 2, MIN_PWD_LENGTH: 8 }];
 test;

ngOnInit() {
 var result = this.States.map(t => t.MIN_PWD_LENGTH);
 this.test = this.States.map(t => t.MIN_PWD_LENGTH);
 console.log('result', result);
}
```

Comment: As he told in the question it is `[MiN_LENGTH = 2, MIN_PWD_LENGTH = 8]` not `[{ MiN_LENGTH: 2, MIN_PWD_LENGTH: 8 }]` which both are total different!

Comment: Thanks I'll check it

Comment: This Is Working.                                                                                                                                                         var x = this.States;
var defaultpwd = x['MIN_PWD_LENGTH'];